# Executable app(.exe) not running via the ASP.Net Webservice(.asmx)

Tags: .net-4.0, iis-7.5, asmx, windows-7-x64

I want to execute a process from the ASP.Net Webservice(.asmx).
    In the Webservice hosted directory, I have a executable app in  "importerapp" folder of the webservice directory. My executable app is ( Named as Import.exe) is working good by double clicking.

```
 My webservice is running with no error but the process is not executed.    

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public string executeProcess(RunMode mode ) 
    {
      Process process = new Process();  

     process.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("importerapp/Import.exe");

        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;  

        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;  

        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;  

        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "mode=" + (int)_runMode ;

        process.Start();  

        process.WaitForExit();  


        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();  

        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();  

        return("Job Submitted OK with params: "+_runMode + error 
             + output +"Exit Code:"+ process.ExitCode );

    }
```

In the browser, The output is as below.

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Job Submitted OK with 
params: Exit   Code:0</string>
```

That means, the "error" and "output" variable is null and exit code is 0 which means success.

But the processing is not doing anything, even not creating logfile( I am using nLog library).

Environment: WIndows7, IIS 7.5, .Net4.0, C#, ASP.Net

Please advise.
Thanks.
Ruhul

Answer (score 0):

```
Job Submitted OK with params: Exit Code:0
```

This, according to your code, means that `_runMode` variable is not initiated. I think you forget to pass the parameter `mode` to your process

Comment: Thanks VMAtm.
 _runMode  is initialized with one default value. So it should not be a problem.
Any other idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Look at your code - there is no default value in your result. Check that.

Comment: Sorry to mention, that is declared as class member with a default value, your comment is valid but it should not be a problem. Thanks a lot.